# Pulse audio: how to disable an output channel?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

My computer is connected to my receiver, and I don't want to play nothing to it through Pulse Audio. How do I disable these channels?

[image]

I want to disable the "HDMI / DisplayPort2" and the "Digital Output (S/PDIF)" channels.

I have two reasons. In Kodi (old XBMC), I can't get 5.1 surround audio if it played through Pulse Audio. The S/PDIF is also connected to my receiver and my music sounds a lot better if I play directly to the digital device.

If Pulse Audio captures these devices, I can't play anything on them. I must kill Pulse Audio first. I just play on them using 2 applications: Kodi for movies and Clementine for music.